# Get Java Bytecode on Android

Tags: java, android, classloader, dalvik

I'm dynamically loading classes on Android through the following code sniplet.

```
if(classes.size() > 0) {
    // Located classes.load and scan them for interfaces.
    DexClassLoader dx = new DexClassLoader(szPath,outdex,null,      c.getClassLoader());
    for(String sz : classes) {
        Class<?> cls = dx.loadClass(sz);
        for(Class<?> i : cls.getInterfaces()) {
            if(i.getName().contains("IPinPad") == true) {
                 // This is a PinPad.
                 return (IPinPad)cls.newInstance();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

classes contains a list of classes descovered in the dex file from previous run code. purpose od this code is to return object instances which implements the IPinPad interface declaration. This all works fine, but in addition I'd like to grab the byte code for the cls.newInstance() object. How should I do this?

I've been playing around with `cls.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream();` but it always returns a null stream, unsure how to specify the resourcename for the class.

Comment: You can't get the Java bytecode from the DEX file, as it does not exist there. You can, in theory, get the Dalvik bytecode, though depending on your eventual purpose it would probably be easier to just open the DEX file and read it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dexlib2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.smali%7Cdexlib2%7C2.0.5%7Cjar) (part of [smali/baksmali](https://code.google.com/p/smali/)) in order to load and read the dalvik bytecode in a dex file. And yes, it should be usable in an Android app as well.

```
DexFile dexFile = DexFileFactory.loadDexFile("/blah/blah.dex", android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
for (ClassDef classDef: dexFile.getClasses()) {
    if (classDef.getType().equals("Lthe/class/to/look/for;")) {
        // handle/inspect/process the class as needed
    }
}
```